# Scene elements showing twice in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm building a UI with javafx for this little board game application I made. It just has Othello and Connect Four, and you can also add players to keep score. Scores are just recorded in a .txt file and are loaded when the program starts.

The main menu is a Scene with the scoreboard, created from the .txt file, and the buttons. I can add players and they get written to the file and load just fine, the problem happens when I try to reload the players in the .txt file and refresh the scoreboard. I try to refresh the scene but the scoreboard gets printed twice.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    static Stage window;

    public void refreshMainMenu() {

        Button c4button = new Button("Connect Four");
        Button othelloButton = new Button("Othello");
        Button addPlayerButton = new Button("Add New Player");
        Button quitButton = new Button("Quit");

        GridPane scoreboard = new GridPane();
        if(!Player.loadPlayers()) {
            Label label = new Label("No Players Yet");
            scoreboard.add(label, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            Label label = new Label("Scoreboard:\n");
            Label temp1 = new Label("Name\t");
            Label temp2 = new Label("Othello Wins\t");
            Label temp3 = new Label("Connect Four Wins\t");
            Label temp4 = new Label("Total Wins\t");
            scoreboard.add(label, 0, 0);
            scoreboard.add(temp1, 0, 1);
            scoreboard.add(temp2, 1, 1);
            scoreboard.add(temp3, 2, 1);
            scoreboard.add(temp4, 3, 1);

            for(int i = 0; i < Player.getPlayerList().size(); i++) {
                Label temp5 = new Label(Player.getPlayerList().get(i).getName());
                Label temp6 = new Label(Integer.toString(Player.getPlayerList().get(i).getOthelloWins()));
                Label temp7 = new Label(Integer.toString(Player.getPlayerList().get(i).getConnectFourWins()));
                Label temp8 = new Label(Integer.toString(Player.getPlayerList().get(i).getTotalWins()));

                scoreboard.add(temp5, 0, i+2);
                scoreboard.add(temp6, 1, i+2);
                scoreboard.add(temp7, 2, i+2);
                scoreboard.add(temp8, 3, i+2);
            }
        }
        scoreboard.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox buttons = new HBox(20);
        buttons.getChildren().addAll(c4button, othelloButton, addPlayerButton, quitButton);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(scoreboard, buttons);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene mainMenu = new Scene(layout, 600, 300);

        window.setScene(mainMenu);
        window.show();

        c4button.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                ConnectFour.playConnectFour();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        othelloButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                Othello.playOthello();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        addPlayerButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                String newPlayer = TextBox.display("Add Player", "Enter Player Name:");
                Player.addNewPlayer(newPlayer);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            refreshMainMenu();
        });
        quitButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            boolean response = ConfirmBox.display("Exit Board Master","Are you sure?");
            if(response)
                window.close();
        });
        window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            boolean response = ConfirmBox.display("Exit Board Master","Are you sure?");
            if(response)
                window.close();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Board Master");
        refreshMainMenu();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There are also confirmation and text box popups:

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class ConfirmBox {

    private static boolean response;

    static boolean display(String title, String message) {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        Button yesButton = new Button("Yes");
        Button noButton = new Button("No");
        yesButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            response = true;
            window.close();
        });
        noButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            response = false;
            window.close();
        });

        Label label = new Label(message);
        StackPane toplayout = new StackPane(label);

        HBox centerlayout = new HBox(10);
        centerlayout.getChildren().addAll(yesButton, noButton);
        centerlayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        layout.setTop(toplayout);
        layout.setCenter(centerlayout);

        Scene alertBox = new Scene(layout, 250, 60);
        window.setScene(alertBox);
        window.showAndWait();

        return response;
    }
}
```

And:

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class TextBox {

    private static String response;

    static String display(String title, String message) {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        Label label = new Label(message);
        TextField input = new TextField();
        Button confirmButton = new Button("Confirm");
        confirmButton.setOnAction(e -> {
             response = input.getText();
             window.close();
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(5);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, input, confirmButton);

        Scene textBox = new Scene(layout, 250, 80);
        window.setScene(textBox);
        window.showAndWait();

        return response;
    }
}
```

And the player class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Player {

    private String name;
    private int totalWins = 0;
    private int othelloWins = 0;
    private int connectFourWins = 0;

    private static ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>(1);

    private Player(String input) {
        name = input;
    }
    private Player(String input, int othello, int connectFour, int total) {
        name = input;
        othelloWins = othello;
        connectFourWins = connectFour;
        totalWins = total;
    }

    void addOthelloWin() {
        othelloWins++;
        totalWins++;
    }
    void addConnectFourWin() {
        connectFourWins++;
        totalWins++;
    }
    void changeName(String input) {
        name = input;
    }

    static ArrayList<Player> getPlayerList() {
        return playerList;
    }
    static Player getPlayer(String input) {
        for(int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++) {
            if(playerList.get(i).name.equals(input)) {
                return playerList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    int getOthelloWins() {
        return othelloWins;
    }
    int getConnectFourWins() {
        return connectFourWins;
    }
    int getTotalWins() {
        return totalWins;
    }

    static void printWins() {
        System.out.println("Names\t\tOthello\t\tConnect4\t\tTotal" + "\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(playerList.get(i).name + "\t\t\t" + playerList.get(i).othelloWins + "\t\t\t" +
                    playerList.get(i).connectFourWins + "\t\t\t" + playerList.get(i).totalWins);
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void addNewPlayer(String name) throws IOException {
        Player newPlayer = new Player(name);
        playerList.add(newPlayer);

        File file = new File("player_Data.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        writer.write(newPlayer.name + "\t\t" + newPlayer.othelloWins + "\t\t" + newPlayer.connectFourWins + "\t\t" + newPlayer.totalWins + System.lineSeparator());
        writer.close();
    }

    static boolean loadPlayers(){
        Scanner input;

        try {
            File file = new File("player_Data.txt");
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            try {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String[] lineArray = line.split("\t\t");
                Player newPlayer = new Player(lineArray[0], Integer.parseInt(lineArray[1]), Integer.parseInt(lineArray[2]), Integer.parseInt(lineArray[3]));
                playerList.add(newPlayer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Player data incorrectly formatted.");
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void recordWins() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("player_Data.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++) {
            writer.write(playerList.get(i).name + "\t\t" + playerList.get(i).othelloWins + "\t\t" + playerList.get(i).connectFourWins + "\t\t" + playerList.get(i).totalWins + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Here is a sample run:
[Opening with no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj6Br.png)

[Adding player.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjbR0.png)

[Scoreboard showing twice after adding a player.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKFhJ.png)

[After closing and restarting the program, scoreboard shows that players were added and loaded correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UwLx.png)

This is my first attempt at a javafx application, so maybe I am confused on how it works. My thinking is that we have one window to show different scenes. I have one scene be a main menu which gets shown by the refreshMainMenu(). The main menu gets refreshed whenever we add a new player, but if we click the Othello or Connect Four buttons, then we switch to either a scene for Othello or a scene for Connect Four. That's why after the user clicks add new player and adds the player, I call refreshMainMenu() which will create the main menu scene again from scratch with the new player data. I've tried moving where I call refreshMainMenu() and also tried closing the window and then calling refreshMainMenu(). Closing the window and calling refresh again results in the same issue of the scoreboard being duplicated.

This is also my first post here, so I'm sorry if I'm breaking any rules or the question has been asked before. I searched and couldn't find any posts that really helped with my case. There's also classes that run Othello and Connect Four games, but they still run in the console for now as I haven't gotten there yet. I can include the code if necessary.

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__, nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code

Comment: @kleopatra It is kind of minimal in this case :)

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `refreshMainMenu()` method doubles existing players on the players list. `if(!Player.loadPlayers())` loads players stored in txt file without checking wheater the player is already stored in the `Player.playerList` list.

I decided to help because you put much effort to create the question and by the quality of the code I can see the you have just begun using JavaFx. Couple good advices. You don't need to change the scene every time you want to refresh. It is very bad practice. Learn about observable collections in JavaFx. Player should not store the list of players. And first of all - learn to use debugger.

Comment: Holy crap I'm such an idiot.Thank you. That was just an oversight on my part. I totally thought it was something with javafx. I've used the debugger a couple times, but since I thought the issue was with javafx I was hesitant to use it, knowing next to nothing about javafx. If you don't mind a follow up question, what do you mean we don't need to change the scene every time we want to refresh? When I comment out the refreshMainMenu() after adding a player, the scoreboard doesn't update on the main menu even though a player gets added to the file.

Comment: Use single scene instance. Manipulate Node objects on the scene to get desired state. Setting new Scene every time you need to rerender view is utterly inefficient.